# How to replace an object of a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to update a specific object value of an array. So my way of doing was to delete the old object and insert in the same index with updated values.

```
      let thisTodoIndex = oldTodos.findIndex((t) => t.id === getTodoId);
  let thisTodo = oldTodos[thisTodoIndex];

  thisTodo = { ...thisTodo, isCompleted: !getStatus };

  let updatedTodo = oldTodos.filter(td => td.id !== getTodoId);
  console.log(updatedTodo); // working fine
  console.log(thisTodo); // working fine
  console.log(thisTodoIndex); //working fine
  updatedTodo = updatedTodo.splice(thisTodoIndex,0,thisTodo); // becoming empty

  console.log(updatedTodo);
```

Image of the arrray for ref:

[image]

Comment: The `.splice()` method returns an array of the elements that were deleted, since your delete count is `0`, you'll get an empty array. Instead, `splice()` modifies `updatedTodo` in place rather than returning a newly modified array.

Answer (score 0):

You can update object without delete its, for example:

```js
const oldTodos = [
  {
    id: 1,
    todoText: "Create",
    inComplete: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    todoText: "Create",
    inComplete: true
  },
]

const getTodoId = 1

const index = oldTodos.findIndex( _ => _.id == getTodoId)

oldTodos[index] = {
  ...oldTodos[index],
  todoText: "New Text"
}

console.log(oldTodos)
```

Answer (score -2):

I was doing it a wrong way.

```
  console.log(thisTodoIndex); //working fine
  updatedTodo.splice(thisTodoIndex,0,thisTodo);

  console.log(updatedTodo);
```

I was storing `updatedTodo.splice(thisTodoIndex,0,thisTodo)` in a variable and then I was returning that. This works now.